# How to run simple MYSQL query using rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want run a simple MYSQL query using rails

```
Select movie-title, movie-director from moving order by rating desc limit 5;
```

I don't want all the overhead creating models. I just want to run the query.

What is the best way to do this?
I cannot even connect

Here is my the code from my controller

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection ({
:adapter => "mysql2",
:host => "some-rds.amazon.com",
:username => "root",
:password => "root",
:database => "blah"})
```

This will generate this error
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

thanks

Answer (score 16):

```
movie_title = 'Planet of the Apes'
sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(movie_title)}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use ModelName.find_by_sql("your sql query") in your console.

Answer (score 1):

Config the database connection in

> /config/database.yml

In Controller,

```
def connect_and_fetch
    result_obj =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select column from table")
    @rows = []
    index = 0
    result_obj.each do |row|
      @rows[index] = row
      index += 1
    end
end
```

In html view,

```
Result : <%= @rows%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey for the fist steep make sure you have the eight gem and install support for Mysql:

**Configuring Rails Applications**

In this section, we will modify the Rails application servers so that they start working with the database server we have just set up.

**Installing Database Server Libraries**

The first thing to do is installing the necessary database libraries. In our case, it is MySQL's development package.

Run the following to install MySQL development package mysql-devel:

```
yum install -y mysql-devel
```

**Configuring database.yml For Rails**

Database settings for Rails applications are kept inside the database.yml file in /config directory.

Run the following command to edit the database.yml file using the nano text editor:

```
# Make sure to enter your application deployment directory
# Example:
# cd /var/www/my_app

nano config/database.yml
```

Once you open up this file, you will see database settings, divided by environment names. Since an application needs to run using the production environment, let's edit the configuration for that.

Replace the production: YML code block with the following, changing the necessary bits to suit your own set-up configuration, e.g. the IP address etc.

```
# Example:
# production:
#   adapter: mysql
#   encoding: utf8
#   database: [database name]
#   username: [user name]
#   password: [password]
#   host: [server IP address]
#   port: [port number]
#   protocol: [protocol]
#   pool: [connection pool]

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: rails_myapp
  username: rails_myapp_user
  password: pwd
  host: 128.199.233.36
  port: 3306
  pool: 10
```

> Note: As provided in the example above, you might need to specify the
>   protocol.
>
> Note: The pool argument contains the number of maximum simultaneous
>   database connection slots (i.e. pool) available. You need to assess
>   your needs and set a number accordingly.

Save and exit by pressing CTRL+X and confirming with Y.

**Getting The mysql Gem**

Start editing the Gemfile using nano using the following:

```
nano Gemfile
```

Add the following line to the file:

```
gem 'mysql'
```

Save and exit by pressing CTRL+X and confirming with Y.

Install the new gem using bundle:

```
bundle install
```

And that's it! From now on, your Rails application servers will be using your brand new database server for all operations.

you can find more info in:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/scaling-ruby-on-rails-setting-up-a-dedicated-mysql-server-part-2