# Correct syntax for dependent subqueries in ActiveRecord (rails 3.2.9, mysql innodb 5.5)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following query that uses dependent subqueries:

```
    select * from posts as p where exists ( 
       select 1 from content_feeds as cf where id = p.content_feed_id and content_type = 'youtube' and exists ( 
           select 1 from follows where follower_id = 1 and content_feed_id = cf.id 
       ) 
     )  
     order by p.id desc limit 15;
```

I need to use the subqueries for performance reasons (avoiding filesort and tmp tables). However I can't figure the syntax/approach to do this with ActiveRecord.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also, I omitted the table structures since I don't *think* they are necessary to answer the question but if needed I can add them.

Comment: Have you tried [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find_by_sql/class) or [ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18750232/how-to-run-simple-mysql-query-using-rails) at all?

Comment: find_by_sql works great for this. Thanks!